# how to alter a single row in v-data-table (not styling, the content)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I wasn't able to find an answer for this use case of v-data-table.I know that you can use template and slots to modify a certain column but what if i want my value to be reflected only in one row? So in my code, everytime a user right clicks on the name column it adds a logo to show the value is copied and then after 3 seconds it removes it from the name -kind of like a toggle effect.

It works well whenever i click on a name on a certain row, and it copies the link value for that specific link by using vue-clipboard's library. However, it also does the same thing for all the other columns that have link. I would like to do it for only one. I couldn't make the vue-clipboard library run in sandbox so i'm sharing my code snippets.

In order to better show the current behavior, this is a screenshot from the v-data-table. (as you can see, it shows the check icon in both rows even though i only click on the first one. The expected behavior would only show the check icon the cell that has been clicked on .[image]

template;

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="tableData"
        class="display-stats"
        :items-per-page="5"
        :footer-props="{
            'items-per-page-options': rowsPerPageItems,
        }"
        >
        <template v-slot:[`item.name`]="{ item }">
            <span v-if="item.link" class="link-span" @contextmenu="copyLink(item.link)">
            <a class="preview-link" :href="item.preview" target="_blank">{{ item.name }}</a>
            <p v-show="copied">
                <v-icon small :color="green">fas fa-check</v-icon>
            </p>
            </span>
            <span v-else>
            {{ item.name }}
            </span>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>
```

script;

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2'

VueClipboard.config.autoSetContainer = true // add this line
Vue.use(VueClipboard)


interface PriceStats {
  rowsPerPageItems: Number[]
  copied: boolean
}

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Component',

  props: {
    priceData: {
      type: Array as () => Array<PriceStats>,
      default: () => {},
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data(): PriceData {
    return {
      rowsPerPageItems: [10, 20, 30],
      copied: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tableData:{
      get():PriceStats[]{
        if (this.priceData) {
          return this.priceData
        } else {
          return []
        }
      },
      set(newVal:PriceStats){
        this.tableData=newVal
      }
    },

    headers(): DataTableHeader[] {
      return [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          value: 'name',
        },
        {
          text: 'Age',
          value: 'age',
          align: 'center',
        },
        {
          text: 'Salary',
          value: 'salary',
        },
        {
          text: 'Position',
          value: 'format',
        },
        {
          text: 'Date',
          value: 'date',
        },
        {
          text: 'Premium',
          value: 'premium',
          align: 'right',
        },
      ]
    },

  },
  methods: {
    copyLink(previewLink: string) {
      this.$copyText(previewLink).then(
        (e) => {

          this.copied = true
          setTimeout(()=> {
            this.copied = false
          },3000)
        },
        (e) => {
          need an error logic here
          this.copied = false
        }
      )
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: how do you uniquely identify a user(row)?

Comment: that's the question i'm asking too! You mean i could perhaps use array indexes? but not sure how that is reflected on v-data-table

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that users cannot have the same name, you can check if the name is equal to the one on the row copied then display the icon there.
like this:

```
<v-data-table ...>
<span v-if="item.link" class="link-span"  @contextmenu="copyLink(item.link,item.name)">
            <a class="preview-link" :href="item.preview" target="_blank">{{     item.name }}</a>
           <p v-show="item.name == copiedName">
             <v-icon small :color="green">fas fa-check</v-icon>
           </p>
            </span>
     </v-data-table>
```

`copiedName` can be an external variable that you assign the name of the user using the function `copyLink`

...

```
copyLink(previewLink: string,name) {
      this.$copyText(previewLink).then(
        (e) => {

          this.copied = true
          this.copiedName = name

          setTimeout(()=> {
            this.copied = false
          },3000)
        },
        (e) => {
          need an error logic here
          this.copied = false
        }
      )
    },
```